# BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION (in Oracle) EXIT_MESSAGE (2500 bytes) too small

Tags: spring, spring-batch

ETA: Clarifying context: By default, BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION.EXIT_MESSAGE (populated with error code of failed step) is defined as VARCHAR2(2500).

When a step fails, the error message is typically stack trace on order of 10k - 15k.  The first 2500 characters rarely gives insight into problem.  Two questions:
1) Can I safely change the column type from VARCHAR2(2500) to VARCHAR2(4000)?  Or better still, CLOB?
2) Do I need to make any changes in Spring Batch to say, "It's okay to send exit_message of 4000, or unlimited with CLOB, rather than cutting it off at 2500 characters"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@KevinKirkpatrick,
I believe you can increase the EXIT_MESSAGE length to varchar2(4000) or change the datatype to a CLOB. Both of these options seem to work based on my testing.

The jobRepository needs to be updated to include the max_varchar-length.
For Example:

```
<batch:job-repository id="j1" max-varchar-length="100000"/>
```

I don't know if this is a good solution though. Changing the datatype on a Spring Batch table seems less than ideal.